# HTML5 alternative for ::-moz-list-number

Tags: css, html

How to define a style for the list numbering in HTML5, which is compatible with [`<ol reversed>`](http://www.impressivewebs.com/reverse-ordered-lists-html5/)?

I found [`::-moz-list-number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3A-moz-list-number) but it works just in Firefox. Does anybody know a better alternative to do the same?

Comment: Why would *HTML* provide an alternative to a pseudo-element?

Comment: @BoltClock Read it as "a CSS (what ever version) pseudo-element, which works in modern browsers, supporting HTML5".

Comment: @BoltClock Can you show me the answer you are referencing by "This question has been asked before and already has an answer"?

Answer (score 0):

I totally missed the very obvious `reverse` part. It looks like you might need to do `<li><span>Item</span></li>` and unstyle in the `<span>` what you styled to the `<li>`.

---

Old Answer (might be useful for some).

You can style `::before` and add `content: counter(someCounter)`.

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) ". ";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here's a quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/toggchgd/1/

Comment: This ignores the part "which is compatible with `<ol reversed>`".

Comment: Damn. Shocked there's no option for that when defining the counter. I know you can do this but it's pretty useless unless you know the amount of items in the list: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/toggchgd/2/

Comment: Looks like your only option is putting a `<span>` around the text as well and unstyling what you did to the `li` unfortunately.

Comment: Here goes an approach that requires just a bit of JS: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/toggchgd/3/

Comment: "Shocked there's no option for that when defining the counter." I suspect the problem is in CSS not being able to determine the number of elements to count down from in advance. Remember that counters can have arbitrary scopes.

Comment: Yeah. For some reason I thought that since the `reversed` property allowed it to happen it could be available in some way.